# Segmentation fault when assigning integer to pointer

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to assign my node value to a pointer, but gdb gives me segmentation fault when the code is ran. What can I do?

```
void biggerPotion(No* node, int bottleSize, int *aux){
        if(node == NULL)
            return;
        maiorPocao(node>left, bottleSize, aux);
        maiorPocao(node->right, bottleSize, aux);
        if((node->value >=  garra) && (node-> value < *aux))
            *aux = node->value;      //here is the issue
    }
```

Other relevant parts of the code are:

```
for(i=0; i< nBottles;i++){
        a = 1000;             //i declared that 
        biggerPotion(potions,bottleSize[i],&a);
    }
```

Comment: I understand raiz is root but garra translates to claw. Is there a better Portuguese translation for that?

Comment: Sorry, garra is short for "garrafa", that means bottle

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the error. Remove as much code as you possibly can, making sure that the code remaining still replicates the error.

Comment: I took off the recursive part, and still got the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since the errant line is:

```
*aux = node->value;
```

then either `aux` is the problem or `node` is (because they're the only two pointers being dereferenced on that line).

I would print them both out before executing that `if` block just to be certain:

```
fprintf(stderr, "node is %p, aux is %p\n", node, aux);
```

Given the large use of `node` and small use of `aux`, it's *probably* the latter that's causing the issue, in which case you should examine what you're passing to the top-level call of `biggerPortion`. You should post that top-level call, including the declaration of whatever variable you're passing in.

In any case, you can test that by simply changing:

```
*aux = node->value;
```

into:

```
{
    int temp = node->value;
}
```

If the problem disappears then it's definitely the `aux` pointer being wrong somehow. Make sure you *are* actually passing in a pointer, such as with:

```
int myVar;
biggerPotion(rootNodePtr, 42, &myVar);
```

Comment: So, i tried it out and got this:
´node is 006D0E58, aux is 00401D00´

Comment: @João: sorry, caught me mid-edit. It certainly *looks* reasonable- `0x06...` and `0x04...` seem feasible as heap and stack memory, but specifically they're not null). It'd be handy to see the initial call to the function as well (including the declaration of the var you're passing in).

Comment: That's the initial declaration: " biggerPotion(potions,bottleSize[i],aux);

Comment: @João: and the declaration of `aux`? If that's an `int`, you'll need to pass `&aux`.

Comment: For some reason, all values I get from the *aux print are adresses.
I tried passing &a, &aux, and aux.

Comment: Just tried out this

`{
    int temp = node->value;
}`
And got no problems!

Comment: Hey there, just worked it out...seems like in my test printf, I was actually printing aux's address, instead of *aux!
Thanks for the help :)